# $2^X$ separable $\implies$ $X$ separable

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and let $2^X$ have the Vietoris topology. I know from an article that $2^X$ is separable only if $X$ is separable, but the article omits the proof as it is apparently obvious.

Given $D$ is a countable dense subset of $2^X$, how can I derive a countable dense subset $C$ of $X$?

I have no intuition for what $C$ should be. Candidates that I have tried end up being either not dense or not countable.

Comment: For the other direction, if $D$ is dense in $X$ the set of all finite subsets of $D$ (which are all closed so members of $2^X$ as $X$ is $T_1$) is a dense subset of $2^X$.

Comment: And an example to see we need $T_1$ in the reverse implication: take $X$ as the included point topology (say wrt $0$) on $\Bbb R$ (which is $T_0$ but not $T_1$) and note that $2^X$ has an uncountable discrete and open subset $\{\{x\}\mid x \neq 0\}$ (so is far from separable) while $X$ has a dense subspace of size $1$, namely $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $F\in D$ pick a point $x_F\in F$, and let $C=\{x_F:F\in D\}$. If $U$ is any non-empty open set in $X$, $\{H\in 2^X:H\subseteq U\}$ is open in $2^X$, so it contains some $F\in D$, and clearly $x_F\in U$.